# Javascript - dynamically creating an ID for an element -

Tags: javascript, html

I have some JS in an HTML template. How do I syntax-wise calculate some value, store it in a variable and then use it as the ID for an element? It's not working right now. Can anyone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

```
if (key == "down"){
    var tri_id = "triangle" + status_JSON['down'][1];
    document.getElementById(tri_id).innerHTML = "<img class='voting' src='images/vote_grey.png'></img>";
    document.getElementById(status_JSON['down'][1]).innerHTML = status_JSON["down"][0];
}
```

DOM is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var triangle_id = "triangle" + "{{each[1].key()}}";
</script>
<div class='votes_div'>
    <table id="votes_table">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href='javascript:registerVote("{{each[1].key()}}")'>
                <span id=triangle_id title='vote if you think this review is helpful'><img class='voting' src='../../../../images/vote_grey.png'></img></span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Sorry I'm a a beginner !

Comment: `document.getElementById(tri_id)` **(no quotes)** will work, but only if there's actually an element with that ID already in the DOM.

Comment: I have tried without the quotes and it still doesn't work - and yes, that id is already in the dom -- I keep getting error :Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Comment: Then either you're wrong, and there is no element with that ID, or this code is running before the DOM is ready. How about [an SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that reproduces the problem? There are plenty of tools to help you create one: http://jsfiddle.net, http://jsbin.com, http://codepen.io, etc.

Comment: Would you mind showing us the corresponding HTML?

Comment: Does the markup actually have an element with `id="triangle_id"`? What is the **actual** HTML that the browser sees?

Comment: yes it is in the table/tr/td/span with that id ---> I tried quotes around it but that read it literally instead of the variable.  I'm having to dynamically create the triangle ID because I'm looping through different data instances and need to create unique ID's for each loop - incorporating a string "triangle" + unique identifier.  I couldn't just use the unique identifier because I have used that elsewhere in the loop which did work successfully. Thanks for taking the time - much appreciated

Comment: I'm thinking it's probably totally not ok to define a variable in js and then use it in the template?  How else to create the string?

Comment: There is also no element with an id that is `id` - which is what your 4th line of JS is looking for.

Comment: omg - right of course.  Well did change it - still same error

Comment: THANK YOU ALL- I GOT IT WORKING  - love this forum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTML doesn't have any access to the JavaScript environment. So this won't work as you expect:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var triangle_id = "triangle1234"
</script>
<span id=triangle_id>
```

The span tag will have id "triangle_id" (literally), not "triangle1234".

It looks like you are using some kind of a language to embed dynamic number into HTML. You will have to do it directly in the tag:

```
<span id="triangle{{each[1].key()}}">
```

Comment: that's what I was suspecting when I was writing it --- cool - didn't know you could do that - thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The code:

```
document.getElementById("tri_id")
```

Will actually look for a DOM element *called* `tri_id`.  To use the variable's value, use:

```
document.getElementById(tri_id)
```

Comment: Gentlemen, read the comments on the OP.